# Is it possible to only declare a type at the beginning but define it later in C?

Tags: c, typedef

In this example, the full definition of `Book` is before its usage in `main()`. Is there a way to declare `Book` as a type without specifying the details, but define the details after `main()`. Thanks.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_typedef.htm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Books {
   char title[50];
   char author[50];
   char subject[100];
   int book_id;
} Book;

int main( ) {

   Book book;

   strcpy( book.title, "C Programming");
   strcpy( book.author, "Nuha Ali"); 
   strcpy( book.subject, "C Programming Tutorial");
   book.book_id = 6495407;

   printf( "Book title : %s\n", book.title);
   printf( "Book author : %s\n", book.author);
   printf( "Book subject : %s\n", book.subject);
   printf( "Book book_id : %d\n", book.book_id);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking "is it possible to reserve the name `Book` at the beginning of my source code and then define it fully later?"

Comment: It can be done, though in the context of this program I don't see much point in doing so.  Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: `Book book;` need the full definition of _Book_, and it is the same after to access its fields

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do since you access the members of `Book` directly and you definitely need a complete type for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can forward declare it and typedef before hand:

```
typedef struct Books Book;
```

This will allow you to use pointers of type `Book*`, but it won't allow you to dereference them (whether with `*` or with `->`) or declare objects of this type (as with `Book book;`).

The closest thing to accomplishing your stated goals would probably be with 
a function that returns a pointer to an allocated `Book` and then with accessor functions.

This compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Books Book; //forward declare + typedef
Book *Book__alloc(void);
//accessor functions:
char*Book__title(Book*);
char*Book__author(Book*);
char*Book__subject(Book*);
int *Book__id(Book*);


int main( ) {

   Book *book = Book__alloc();
   if(!book) return EXIT_FAILURE;

   strcpy( Book__title(book), "C Programming");
   strcpy( Book__author(book), "Nuha Ali"); 
   strcpy( Book__subject(book), "C Programming Tutorial");
   *Book__id(book) = 6495407;

   printf( "Book title : %s\n", Book__title(book));
   printf( "Book author : %s\n", Book__author(book));
   printf( "Book subject : %s\n", Book__subject(book));
   printf( "Book book_id : %d\n", *Book__id(book));

   free(book);

   return 0;
}

//provide definitions after the fact
struct Books {
   char title[50];
   char author[50];
   char subject[100];
   int book_id;
};
Book *Book__alloc(void){ return malloc(sizeof(Book)); }
char*Book__title(Book*X){ return X->title; }
char*Book__author(Book*X){ return X->author; }
char*Book__subject(Book*X){ return X->subject; }
int *Book__id(Book*X) { return &X->book_id; }
```

Comment: It sounds like if the compiler ever allow two passes, it would be possible. But the compiler by definition only pass the input file once?

Comment: @user1424739 Correct.  C compilers go though a source file in a single pass, so it won't know about a definition further down in the file.

Comment: @user1424739 This particular thing with the forward declared functions is allowed because even in simple single pass compilers, the connection between the forward declarations can be done with the linker. Modern compilers will construct an AST, though, and walk it as many times as needed in order to spit out something more optimal.

Comment: @user1424739: Yes, the compiler makes a single pass.  This technique is most useful when you have an opaque type in a library — where the implementation details are hidden in a separate implementation file.  Inside a single file, there really isn't a benefit.

Comment: @user1424739 If I compile it with a recent `gcc` at `-O3` the accessors will get generated because I haven't made them `static`, but the calls will get all inlined: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ugabbc . Modern compilers don't spit out code as soon as possible. They construct parse trees and walk them repeatedly, looking for optimization opportunities. The rules of the language, however, do allow for a simple true single pass compiler such as tinycc because the "second pass" can be done with the linker.

Answer (score 2):

Although it has been commented that this is possible, I dont see it so, so my answer is No. Simply because the type Book is already used in main(), e.g. how could

```
strcpy( book.author, "Nuha Ali");
```

actually be treated by the compiler if it does not know about the Books structure ?
It is possible in functions declarations, like this:

```
typedef struct Books Book;
void foo(struct Books *aBookPtr);
```

This because the compiler can happily live with the knowledge its a pointer 
and only needs details in implementation. Hope this helps.